# Swift move duration really short SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am have a program in which a sprite node falls from the top of the screen to the bottom. When it reaches the bottom, it gets put back up to the top before falling again. It does this over and over. Everything works perfectly except for the duration. The duration is always really quick. Here is my code:

```
if fruit1.position.y == startPosition {
        //Generate random number from 6 to 16
        fallDuration = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(10) + 6)

        moveActionDown = SKAction.moveByX(0.0, y: CGFloat(-height - fruit1.frame.height - 100), duration: fallDuration)

        fruit1.runAction(moveActionDown)

        println(fallDuration)
    }
```

This code is called every 0.2 seconds using an NSTimer. When the code runs, the actual duration it takes to complete the action is 2 or 3 seconds at the very most. However the `println` is printing out expected numbers i.e. 10, 15, 12, 8.

This is confusing me because the documentation says that the moveByX duration parameter is in seconds. And also if I use moveToY instead, the duration works as expected.

Comment: There's no gravity pulling on the `physicsBody` obviously(?) Also: don't use `NSTimer` for this, just use a sequence restoring the startPosition when the moveActionDown is completed.

Comment: I'm not using gravity, I am literally just using the moveByX function. And if I were to use a sequence to move it back up when it has reached the bottom, wouldn't I see the fruit moving back up the screen? How would I be able to make this movement back up to the top invisible to the user? Would I just give it a duration of 0?

Comment: Exactly. Any action with a duration of 0 will happen immediately on the next draw-cycle.

Comment: Okay one more thing: If I am not using the NSTimer to call the fall movement, how would I make it keep happening over and over? i.e. once the sequence containing the fall movement and the move to top movement has been executed, it would stop and the sprite would just be sitting at the top. How could I make this sequence start again when the sprite is back at the top?

Comment: `SKAction.repeatActionForever` is what you're looking for.